# How do I assign values to multiple columns in a dataframe by row?

Tags: r

```
animals <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=2,ncol=3))
animals[,c("X1","X2","X3")] <- append(rep("puppies",3),rep("kittens",3))
```

I want it to populate kittens puppies across the first row and kittens across the second. I know i could use byrow in a matrix and cbind, but does a dataframe allow for this way of populating?

Comment: @HubertL This was just an example, the actual return of what I am doing is a long vector, and I want the vector to be applied by row instead of column. Right now my work around is assigning the vector to a matrix by row and then cbind to the dataframe. I just want to avoid that step if possible.

Comment: You don't need the `cbind` if you do `animals[,c("X1","X2","X3")] <- matrix(append(rep("puppies",3),rep("kittens",3)),ncol=3, byrow = TRUE)`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I didn't realize I could populate a dataframe from a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
animals[,c("X1","X2","X3")] <- rep(c("puppies","kittens"),3)
```

Comment: I should have been less lazy when I typed it out. I am trying to get just a vector output to populate over row, so the actual vector being used is more like c("puppies","puppies","puppies","kittens","kittens","kittens").